# Выгрузка из sqlite в словарь

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, dict

У меня есть база данных sqlite в которой есть таблица пользователей

```
id | user_id | name
```

> database.py

```
class Database:
   def select(self):
      cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users;")
      return cursor.fetchall()
```

Я пытаюсь выгрузить все user_id из базы и записать их в словарь в виде ключей, а данными для этих ключей сделать список из 0.

```
import database
db = database.Database()
def user_data():
    userlist = []
    for values in db.select():
        userlist.append(values)
    userdata = dict.fromkeys(userlist, [0]*5)
    return userdata
```

Так у меня получается сделать словарь:

```
userdata = user_data()
print(userdata)
>>> {123456:[0,0,0,0,0], 789123:[0,0,0,0,0]}
```

Но когда я пытаюсь изменить значения у определенного ключа, он меняется везде:

```
userdata[123456][0] = 1
print(userdata)
>>> {123456:[1,0,0,0,0], 789123:[1,0,0,0,0]}
```

Как я понимаю, ключи ссылаются на один объект, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так создать:

```
userdata = {key: [0]*5 for key in userlist}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает!